# JavaScript arrays: string indexed items

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've had a bit of a wakeup to the nature of JavaScript array indexes recently. Pursuing it, I found the following (I'm working with [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) in interpretive mode here):

```
var x=[];
x['a']='a';
console.log(x); // Yields [ a: 'a' ]
console.log(x.length); // yields 0 not 1
x[1]=1;
console.log(x); // Yields [ , 1, a: 'a' ]
console.log(x.length); // Yields 2 not 3 (one for empty 0 space, one for the occupied 1 space)
```

Is `a: 'a'` really what it looks like - an object property embedded in an array - and, thus, isn't counted in the array property `.length`?

Comment: Neato. Didn't even know this was possible. Makes sense though as an array is just an object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In JavaScript, arrays are just objects with some special properties, such as an automatic `length` property, and some methods attached (such as `sort`, `pop`, `join`, etc.). Indeed, `a` will not be counted in your array, since the `length` property of an array only stores *the amount of elements with a property name that can be represented with a 32-bit positive integer*.

And since arrays always automatically define every numbered element up to the highest element with a positive 32-bit int property name, this effectively means the `length` property stores *1 higher than the element with the highest 32-bit integer as a property name*. Thanks @[Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) for correcting me about this in the comments.

Adding properties such as `a` is not forbidden at all, but you should watch out with them, since it might be confusing when reading your code.

There's also a difference in walking through the elements in the array:

To walk through all the numbered elements:

```
for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    //do something
}
```

To walk through every property that's not built-in:

```
for (var i in myArray) {
    //do something
}
```

Note that this loop will also include anything that's included from `Array.prototype` that's not a built-in method. So, if you were to add `Array.prototype.sum = function() {/*...*/};`, it will also be looped through.

To find out if the object you're using is indeed an array, and not just an object, you could perform the following test:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(myObject) === '[object Array]') {
    //myObject is an array
} else if (typeof myObject === 'object') {
    //myObject is some other kind of object
}
```

See [@artem's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27573067/1256925#comment43575365_27573094): `myObject instanceof Array` might not always work correctly.

Comment: *"only counts the numerable values in the array"* That sounds like it would consider the elements of the array itself. The `length` is always 1 + the "maximum" property name that can be converted to a 32bit integer.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for that correction. I've changed it accordingly in my post.

Comment: `myObject instanceof Array` may return false for some arrays (not sure about node.js, I remember one case when array was passed from another iframe, apparently  in some browsers each window had its own instance of Array constructor). It's always a good idea to do what jQuery does, in this case: `Object.prototype.toString.call(myObject) === '[object Array]'`

Comment: You need to correct *can be represented with a 32-bit integer* to *can be represented with a 32-bit **positive** integer **(or zero)***. Negative values don't count towards the `length` property.

Comment: @artem Since this is node.js it runs in a single process and the `Array` constructor will always be the same. Even if not one should rather use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) for the check.

Answer (score 3):

That's correct, and it's a good illustration of the fact that that new Array you've created is really just a special kind of Object. In fact, `typeof []` is `'object'`! Setting a named property on it (which might be written more cleanly here as `x.a = 'a'`) is really setting a new property to the object wrapper around your "real" array (numbered properties, really). They don't affect the length property for the same reason that the `Array.isArray` method doesn't.

Comment: There is no "object wrapper" around the array. The array **is** the object.

Comment: Yes, that's technically true. But if you're using an array it's because you specifically want the ordered list piece, and so it makes sense to think of it as different (and having different uses) than `Object`. The `Number` type is also technically an object (that is it inherits from `Object.prototype`), but it's really unhelpful to think of it as one. My term "object wrapper" is just an abstraction to distinguish an array from a plain object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct. This works because pretty much everything in JavaScript is an object, including arrays and functions, which means that you *can* add your own arbitrary string properties. That's not you say that you *should* do this.

Arrays (`[]`) should be indexed using nonnegative integers. Objects (`{}`) should be "indexed" using strings.

Comment: *Pretty much everything in JavaScript is an object*. I guess you mean "all values in JavaScript are objects, except primitives, which include numbers, strings, null, and undefined". And why should you not put string properties on arrays? It's a perfectly valid technique depending on the situation.